# Focus issue in android webview cordova

Tags: android, cordova, webview, ionic-framework

Hello friends i m new in cordova and i integrate webview in my ionic application so below is my code

Hello.java

```
public class Hello extends CordovaPlugin {


 @Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

    if (action.equals("greet")) {



         Context context = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();

          Intent intent = new Intent(context,Main.class);

          cordova.startActivityForResult((CordovaPlugin)this,intent,100);

          callbackContext.success();


        return true;

    } else {

        return false;

       }
    }
  }
```

Main.java

```
public class Main extends CordovaActivity {


 WebView mWebView;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_webview);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    mWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);


    mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/");

}
```

}

**EDIT**
**layout_webview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability = "blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

When i run above code i can not focus in google search edittext in my webview so any idea how can i solve this? your all suggestions are appreciable

**EDIT 2**

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
mWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN | View.FOCUS_UP);
mWebView.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(true);
mWebView.requestFocus();
mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/");
```

**EDIT 3**

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

    mWebView.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(true);
    mWebView.requestFocus();
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/");

    mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                        v.requestFocus();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: jaydroider: check my edit part in my question

Answer (score 1):

Try with this.

Remove android:descendantFocusability = "blocksDescendants" which prevent child layout from getting focused.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


  <WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Add this.

Might be you enable sensitive touch.

```
Webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN|View.FOCUS_UP);
```

For sensitive touch.

```
Webview.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(true);
```

**Alternative 2.**

```
mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { 
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       switch (event.getAction()) { 
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
               if (!v.hasFocus()) { 
                   v.requestFocus(); 
               } 
               break; 
       } 
       return false; 
    }
});
```

**Alternative 3**

```
mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            v.requestFocusFromTouch();  
            break;
    }               
    return false;
 }
```

});

Hope this helps.

Comment: jaydroider: Not working i cant not click button  and can not focus edittext which provide inside webview

Comment: jaydroider :i make change same as you write but still not able to focus inside webview control

Comment: Just try with adding webView.requestFocus() only.

Comment: jaydroider: see my Edit 2 part in my question i did changes as per you suggests but i still not able to focus  inside webview control

Comment: Remove request focus code with focus down and up and check.

Comment: jaydroider:remove that code but still facing same issue

Comment: jaydroider: see my EDIT 3 in my question i make changes but still not able to click webview inside control

Comment: Are you testing with emulator or real device?

Comment: jaydroider: testing with real device

Comment: Check my edited answer. This all alternate working for me bro.

Comment: jaydroider: your 3rd alternative also not working , i m use android webview inside cordova not Cordovawebview

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya have you got working with issue ?

Comment: jaydroider : Yes brother i still facing this issue